# Как найти разницу во времени в бесконечном цикле на Python?

Tags: python, datetime, while

Всем привет. Я пишу приложение, которое выводит название программы, сразу же как только окно программы становится активным. И допустим окно программы активно некоторое врмя, т.е. пользователь что-то в нем делает, я хочу посчитать время которое пользователь потратил в этом приложении пока оно было активно.

Подскажите пожалуйста куда мне следует поставить переменные "start_t" и "end_t", что бы потом вычести одно из другого и это и было время, которое окно программы было открыто\было активным ?

```
import psutil
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
import pandas as pd

active_wind_name = ""

try:
    while True: #Отслеживаем открытое окно.
        pid = wintypes.DWORD()
        active = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        active_window = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(active, 
ctypes.byref(pid))
        pid = pid.value
        end_t = time.time()
        for item in psutil.process_iter():
            if pid == item.pid and item.name() != active_wind_name: #условие нужно что бы в консуольку выводилось название программы, окно которой стало активным.
                active_wind_name = item.name()
                start_t = time.time()
                total_time = end_t - start_t

                print(active_wind_name)
                print(start_t)
                print(end_t)
                print(total_time)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('End_of_app')
```

Пока я получаю в переменных '''start_t''' и '''end_t''' практически одинаковые значения, но почему? Ведь дальше If програ не должна выполнятся, а значит что и текущее вермя должно быть разным.

Пока получаю такой вывод в консоль:

```
pycharm64.exe
1700914204.2883615
1700914203.4906964
-0.7976651191711426
chrome.exe
1700914209.8747118
1700914209.2641647
-0.6105470657348633
pycharm64.exe
1700914215.1525126
1700914213.9167886
-1.2357239723205566
```

Comment: Первое что бросилось в глаза это вот if pid == item.pid and item.name() != active_wind_name: вы уверены что в этом сложном условии вам нужно проверить на неравность с пустой строкой?

Comment: А вообще распечатайте все переменые в условии и наверное поймёте почему if выполняется.

Comment: Что у вам ещё не понятно? То что между start_t и end_t разницы практически нет?

Comment: С пустой строкой я сравниваю при включении программы. Далее я уже присваиваю переменной 

active_wind_name = item.name()

И тут смысл в том, что если активное окно пеменяется, то имена в переменных соотвественно не будут равно и в консоль выведет новое активное окно. 

Т.е. это условие позволяет выводить в консоль название программы только в тот момент когда ее окно становится активным.

Comment: Это в корне не верно.

Comment: Вот самое интересное, то что как раз если включаю Debug то условие то и не выполняется. в выоде получаю:

'''

pycharm64.exe
1700918602.406323
1700918593.2697136
9.136609315872192


'''

Для меня задача изначально казалось простой, но всю голову сломал. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302716/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-python

Comment: Александр, у меня бесконечный цикл. Если убрать active_wind_name = item.name() то будет бесконечно писать в консоль какое приложение в данный момент открыто. Мне этого не нужно. Мне нужно выводить название приложения в момент когда оно становится активным.

Comment: Определитесь что вам конкретно нужно, в текущем ввиде вопрос не понятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ещё можно

```
import time

import win32gui


def main():
    active_window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    start_t = time.time()
    while True:  # Отслеживаем открытое окно.
        time.sleep(0.1)  # не нагружаем просто так процессор

        if active_window_title != win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()):
            end_t = time.time()
            print(f"{active_window_title}  total-time: {end_t-start_t}")
            start_t = time.time()
            active_window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо именно такую цель я и преследовал.